# How to close other elements has opened if click closed one

Tags: jquery, arrays, attributes, each

How to close other elements has opened if click closed one.
Data attribute "aria-expanded" is only different value.

```
<ul id="mobile-menu-mobile">
<li><!-- mobile menu 1 -->
    <a href=#>menu1</a>
    <button aria-expanded="true"></button>
    <ul>...sub-menu...</ul>
</li>
<li><!-- mobile menu 2 -->
    <a href=#>menu1</a>
    <button aria-expanded="false"></button>
    <ul>...sub-menu...</ul>
</li>
<li><!-- mobile menu 3 -->
    <a href=#>menu1</a>
    <button aria-expanded="false"></button>
    <ul>...sub-menu...</ul>
</li>
<li><!-- mobile menu 4 -->
    <a href=#>menu1</a>
    <button aria-expanded="false"></button>
    <ul>...sub-menu...</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I hope to

- when menu 1 is opened and others are not
- click menu 2 or 3,4 (not opened)
- open clicked one and close opened li

Is there a smart solution?

Here is my attempt

```
var bData = jQuery("#mobile-menu-mobile li button").attr("aria-expanded"); 
console.log(bData); 
if (bData === "false") { ????? }
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: didn't understand clearly?

Comment: Closed li's sub ul has "display:none" in css.

Comment: var bData = jQuery("#mobile-menu-mobile li button").attr("aria-expanded");
                console.log(bData);
                if (bData === "false") {
                    ????? 
                }

Comment: Please add your JS code to the question. We can't help you debug code that we can't see.

Comment: How is it getting expanded?Seems like it is more than just the data attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this?

You can click the button or the link

```js
$(function() {
  $(">li>a, >li>button","#mobile-menu-mobile") // link or button
    .on("click touchstart",function(e) { // click or touch on mobile
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel link
    $("[aria-expanded]").attr("aria-expanded",false); // toggle whatever is true
    $("#mobile-menu-mobile>li>ul").slideUp("fast"); // close all
    $(this).parent().find("[aria-expanded]").attr("aria-expanded",true); // set the aria-expanded
    $(this).nextAll("ul").slideDown("slow"); // open the UL
  });  
  $("#mobile-menu-mobile>li>button[aria-expanded=true]").prev().click(); // initialise
});
```

```css
#mobile-menu-mobile>li>ul { display:none }}
[aria-expanded=true] { background-color:green; color:yellow }
[aria-expanded=false] { background-color:red; color:white }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="mobile-menu-mobile">
  <li>
    <!-- mobile menu 1 -->
    <a href=#>menu1</a>
    <button aria-expanded="true"></button>
    <ul>...sub-menu...</ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <!-- mobile menu 2 -->
    <a href=#>menu1</a>
    <button aria-expanded="false"></button>
    <ul>...sub-menu...</ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <!-- mobile menu 3 -->
    <a href=#>menu1</a>
    <button aria-expanded="false"></button>
    <ul>...sub-menu...</ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <!-- mobile menu 4 -->
    <a href=#>menu1</a>
    <button aria-expanded="false"></button>
    <ul>...sub-menu...</ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```